# Knee Articular Cartilage pain

Tags: running, strength, long-distance-running, endurance

Please refer [image](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=knee+articular+cartilage&rlz=1C1CHMO_enIN542IN542&espv=210&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=i-vbUsmbDo7krAfJroCoBQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=923#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=Q7vktxtY0UdsEM%253A%3BL_INq_VE-YAvnM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.eorthopod.com%252Fsites%252Fdefault%252Ffiles%252Fimages%252Fknee_cart_surg_anatomy01.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.eorthopod.com%252Fcontent%252Farticular-cartilage-problems-knee%3B400%3B358) for the cartilage I am talking about.
On the outer side of my left leg I experience pain after running very long distance (marathon).
My doctor said that this pain is common for endurance athletes.
A year back I got this pain after I finished my first half marathon. After some good running practice, I didn't get this pain at all for half marathons.
But then I am getting this pain for full marathons now.

Is there any specific strengthening exercise that will address this issue?
I think there will be many of you having or had the same issue, so can anyone -who overcame this- help me?
Or will I just get used to this?

Answer (score 2):

Pain on the outside of your knee? Many possible causes and I recommend consulting a physio who is experienced with runners.

Most common cause is IT band syndrome.

The illiotibial band is a length of flesh that runs down the outside of almost your entire leg. In some runners, this gets tight with long runs. It then starts rubbing on the tightest point, the bones around your knee, and you get a blister.

Treatment is rest. Prevention is lots of stretching. The web has a ton of information on this.

Comment: Sarge thank you very much for your answer. I know what is illiotibial band and that is not the problem. I was diagnosed by an ortho that the cartilage is the one that is worn & torn. So I want to know if there is any exercise that you people are aware of or tried during this kind of injury.

Comment: Cartilage damage is very slow and difficult to heal as there is no blood vessel supply, it all relies on diffusion. More exercise won't help. Torn cartilage may or may not repair on its own, and with it being worn as well, you are likely looking at a long healing time. Many people I've known with knee cartilage damage/injury eventually required some sort of surgery.